# Org-mode: publishing multiple org files into a single HTML file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am wondering if it is possible to publish multiple org files into a single (consolidated). So, the first level of the TOC would be each of the file, then subsequent levels would be the TOC of each individual Org file.

I checked the [publishing options](http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html#Publishing-options) and I can't see anything. So I am wondering if there would be another option to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be simply accomplished by including the additional org files to your main one. Simply add the following at the start of the file:

```
#+INCLUDE: second.org
#+INCLUDE: third.org
```

There are some nice additional parameters you can set to for example just include parts of a file, etc. For detailed information, look at the manual [11.4 Include files](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html).

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to generate that kind of file automatically (like the sitemap file), but this is good enough for me for now, thanks!

Comment: In fact what I found is that we can use Org publish to publish a sitemap, and then to provide a `:site-function` that will generate that complete listing automatically. So no need to do this by hands.